# neuralnet training time grows exponentially

Tags: r, neural-network

I have a training data set of 60'000 data entries with 28 features each. After training a neural network with all the data crashed R, I used only a subset of the training data and noticed that the training time of the neural network grows exponentially with the number of rows used from the training data.

For 100 rows, training takes 0.5 seconds. For 400 rows, it's 10.5 seconds. For 1000 rows, it's 170 seconds.

My (newbie) questions are: Is this exponential growth expected? What is the intuition behind it? Any hints how to speed up the training (currently I am using a hidden layer of 10x5x10)?

**Update: added code and example data**

```
library(neuralnet)
library(readr)

training_data <- read_csv("traindata.csv",col_names=TRUE, skip=8, col_types = cols(
  .default = col_double(),
  digit = col_character()
))

# Convert the "digits" column to 10 individual binary columns
training_data <- cbind(training_data[, 1:28], nnet::class.ind(training_data$digit))

# DEBUG use first n rows only
training_data <- training_data[1:1000,]

feats <- names(training_data)
f <- paste(feats[1:28],collapse=' + ')
f <- paste('D0 + D1 + D2 + D3 + D4 + D5 + D6 + D7 + D8 + D9 ~',f)
f <- as.formula(f)

nn <- neuralnet(f,training_data,hidden=c(10,5,10),linear.output=FALSE)
```

The training data looks like this:

```
head (training_data)
  C1 C2 C3 C4            C5            C6           C7            C8           C9          C10
1  0  0  0  0 0.00000000000 0.18417366947 0.4061624650 0.40812324930 0.3319327731 0.1767507003
2  0  0  0  0 0.09411764706 0.17913165266 0.2203081232 0.27507002801 0.3334733894 0.2981792717
3  0  0  0  0 0.00000000000 0.04733893557 0.0675070028 0.09719887955 0.1156862745 0.1326330532
4  0  0  0  0 0.00000000000 0.09733893557 0.1268907563 0.13221288515 0.1127450980 0.1238095238
5  0  0  0  0 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.0000000000 0.18515406162 0.3008403361 0.2282913165
6  0  0  0  0 0.00000000000 0.03739495798 0.1812324930 0.26610644258 0.2815126050 0.2732492997
            C11           C12           C13          C14          C15          C16          C17
1 0.07170868347 0.08179271709 0.07338935574 0.1078431373 0.1359943978 0.1280112045 0.1121848739
2 0.24425770308 0.23123249300 0.20938375350 0.1854341737 0.1883753501 0.1875350140 0.1659663866
3 0.13473389356 0.15042016807 0.16554621849 0.1892156863 0.3408963585 0.4490196078 0.2428571429
4 0.11904761905 0.11554621849 0.12142857143 0.1130252101 0.1102240896 0.1330532213 0.1320728291
5 0.22955182073 0.22338935574 0.21344537815 0.2236694678 0.2756302521 0.3422969188 0.2172268908
6 0.24411764706 0.12577030812 0.10098039216 0.1575630252 0.2481792717 0.3191876751 0.2941176471
            C18           C19           C20           C21           C22           C23           C24
1 0.11414565826 0.15042016807 0.22507002801 0.23109243697 0.22338935574 0.23865546218 0.25952380952
2 0.17450980392 0.15686274510 0.18641456583 0.27955182073 0.33151260504 0.26134453782 0.15238095238
3 0.07843137255 0.06722689076 0.06722689076 0.07254901961 0.07268907563 0.08067226891 0.08081232493
4 0.13207282913 0.13221288515 0.11820728291 0.13319327731 0.12941176471 0.11036414566 0.11036414566
5 0.09509803922 0.08361344538 0.07366946779 0.08361344538 0.08851540616 0.08039215686 0.07366946779
6 0.38067226891 0.38627450980 0.29201680672 0.28459383754 0.21694677871 0.05588235294 0.00000000000
            C25           C26          C27 C28 D0 D1 D2 D3 D4 D5 D6 D7 D8 D9
1 0.19467787115 0.00000000000 0.0000000000   0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0
2 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.0000000000   0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
3 0.07044817927 0.00000000000 0.0000000000   0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
4 0.09663865546 0.00000000000 0.0000000000   0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
5 0.08109243697 0.08837535014 0.0637254902   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
6 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.0000000000   0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: No, it should not grow exponentially.  Share some code an a reproducible example.

Comment: As thc said, some code would be helpful. It would be especially nice to know what packages you are using for the modeling, how you set up the training within that package, etc., as well as have some dummy data.

Comment: Thanks, I have added the code and data samples.